# Outputting special characters correctly (unicode) in PERL

Tags: regex, perl, unicode, character

I am trying to get all the file names in the directory and determine which names contain special characters. I am using the regex

```
/[^-a-zA-Z0-9_.]/
```

SAMPLE FILES ( I created using touch ):

```
pdf-2014à014&7_06_64-Os_O&L,_Inc.pdf
pdf-20_06_04-O_OnLine,_Inc.pdf
pdf-20_0_0-Utà_d.wr.pdf
pdf-20_12_28-20.Mga_Grf.Fwd_Notice_KDJFI789&_JFK38.pdf
pdf-2_0_0-C_—_DUKE.pdf
pdf-2_1_3-f_s-M_F_D&A.pdf
pdf_-_2014à014&1007_0617_06264-O_O&L,_Inc.pdf
```

Perl can output the correct name once before I match the name for pattern in regex. Yes perl was somehow able to get match the special character but when outputing the character changes.

```
* pdf-2_0_0-C_—_DUKE.pdf          >        pdf-2_0_0-C_???_DUKE.pdf
```

I can try uncomment this line

```
   #binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
```

and run the commmand script again. Sure the ? marks will be remove but the output is also different.

```
* pdf-2_0_0-C_—_DUKE.pdf          >        pdf-2_0_0-C_â_DUKE.pdf
```

Here is my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use Cwd;

#binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");

my $starting_directory = cwd();

use Term::ANSIColor;

checkForSpecialChar(cwd());


sub checkForSpecialChar{
    my ($source_dir) = @_;

    chdir $source_dir or die qq(Cannot change into "$source_dir");

    find ( sub {
        return unless -f;   #We want files only
        print "\n";
        while(m/([^-a-zA-Z0-9_.])/g){ 
            chomp($_);
            print "DETECTED: |" . $_ . "|\n";
            print $`;
            print color 'bold red';
            print "$1";
            print color 'reset';
            print  $' . "\n";

        }

    }, ".");

    chdir("$starting_directory");
```

Any Idea guys?

UPDATE:
hmm, you guys are right looks like its not a problem with regex. Hi AKHolland, I tried changing the code to look just like yours for testing.  but still produce the same problem with hypen and a small letter a-grave . 
Instead of a small letter a-grave it gives me 
a` when not using binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8"); 
aÌ when using binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use Cwd;
use Encode;
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");

my $starting_directory = cwd();

use Term::ANSIColor;

checkForSpecialChar(cwd());


sub checkForSpecialChar{
   my ($source_dir) = @_;

   chdir $source_dir
       or die qq(Cannot change into "$source_dir");

   find ( sub {
      return unless -f;   #We want files only
     print $_ . "\n";
      $_ = Encode::decode_utf8($_);
      for(my $counter =0; $counter < length($_); $counter++) {
        print Encode::encode_utf8(substr($_,$counter,1)) .  "\n";
      } 

}, ".");
```

chdir("$starting_directory");
}

```
Output with

    binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");

pdf-2_0_0-C_â_DUKE.pdf
p
d
f
-
2
_
0
_
0
-
C
_
â
_
D
U
K
E
.
p
d
f
pdf_-_2014aÌ014&1007_0617_06264-O_O&L,_Inc.pdf
p
d
f
_
-
_
2
0
1
4
a
Ì
0
1
4
&
1
0
0
7
_
0
6
1
7
_
0
6
2
6
4
-
O
_
O
&
L
,
_
I
n
c
.
p
d
f
```

```
OUTPUT without 
    binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");

pdf-2_0_0-C_—_DUKE.pdf
p
d
f
-
2
_
0
_
0
-
C
_
—
_
D
U
K
E
.
p
d
f
pdf_-_2014à014&1007_0617_06264-O_O&L,_Inc.pdf
p
d
f
_
-
_
2
0
1
4
a
̀
0
1
4
&
1
0
0
7
_
0
6
1
7
_
0
6
2
6
4
-
O
_
O
&
L
,
_
I
n
c
.
p
d
f
```

Comment: What's your environment?  [This version](http://ideone.com/GMzugy#) of your code run on OSX outputs correctly.

Comment: Hi Miller,
I am running that code above using Mac OSX. Bash was able to output it correctly. Perl able to print the characters correctly if I use 'print $_' coming from find but after I pass the string to substr function or regex the return string is already different

Comment: Hi guys, I saw similar post like this one http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=316862. in which substr can't handle utf8. I think its some how related to my problem because I tried output those filename  from they work fine until I pass they through a function. I'll will posting If I find a solution to this problem

Answer (score 3):

You need to decode it on the way in and encode it on the way out. Something like this:

```
use Encode;
find ( sub {
    $_ = Encode::decode_utf8($_);
    while(m/([^-a-zA-Z0-9_.])/g){
        my $chr = Encode::encode_utf8($1);
        print "$chr\n"
    }
}, ".");
```

Comment: Yes, file names should be treated as binary data, so they need to be de- and encoded. While Linuxes tend to use UTF-8 for the file names, Windows uses UTF-16 in its NTFS file system. Perl's `Encode` module offers general-purpose `encode` and `decode` functions for this.

Answer (score 1):

The character `—` in `pdf-2_0_0-C_—_DUKE.pdf` is encoded with 3 char in utf-8:

```
char Unicode   UTF-8
—    U+2014    \xe2\x80\x94
```

so, as said @AKHolland, you have to encode it.

Answer (score 0):

The character "—" is the *Em Dash*, from the Unicode character set, with code point U+2014.

Characters with code points from U+0800 to U+FFFF are encoded using **three bytes** in UTF-8.

For a 3-byte encoding, 16 bits of the binary version of the code point, 2014h, are considered. Convert the hex to binary, and you get 0010 0000 0001 0100b.

That's two bytes. Where do we get three bytes from then? That's because, the UTF-8 encoding rules entail:

- In a 3-byte encoding, the 'leading' (highest value) byte must start with three '1' bits followed by one '0' bit.  Thus, our leading byte takes the form 1110 followed by the first 4 bits we have; i.e. 11100010b or E2h.
- All 'continuation' bytes (those after the leading byte) start with '10'. Thus, our second byte becomes 10 followed by the next 6 bits we have; i.e. 10000000b or 80h.
- Likewise, the third byte (which is the second continuation byte) becomes 10 followed by our remaining 6 bits; i.e. 10010100b or 94h.

Your line `binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");` merely **encodes the output** going on STDOUT to UTF-8. However, as mentioned in the comments to another answer, the Windows file system (NTFS) uses *UTF-16* for filenames - and a UTF-16 encoding uses *two bytes* for encoding characters in the said range, not three. These 2 bytes are just numerically equal to the code point itself, 2014h.

Thus, you also need to **decode the input**. 
AKHolland's answer tells you how.